# Passing the result of a Fetch function to Parent Prop

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, fetch, vue-component

I'm aware there is many questions about passing between Child to Parent Components, however, all the questions and guides I've seen use a Form Input to display how the $emit function works, and I have had no success in translating this to the result of an API call.

My question is, how do I refactor this code to pass the 'data' upwards into my parent components 'TranslatedText' Prop? It confuses me as I have no input, just the data response. Any tips appreciated.

ParentComponent.vue

```
  <template>
     <translation-button v-model="translatedText" />
    </template>

    props: {
    translatedText: '',
   },
```

ChildComponent.Vue

```
    <template>
      <b-button type="is-primary" @click="loadTranslations()">Übersetzen</b-button>
    </template>
    
<script>
export default {
  name: "TranslationButton",

  props: {
    TranslatedText: ''
  },

  methods: {
     loadTranslations() { 
      fetch('http://localhost:3000/ccenter/cc_apis')
        .then(function(response) {
          return response.text();
        })
        .then(function(data) {
          console.log(data);
      })
      .finally(() => {
        this.$emit('loadTranslations', this.TranslatedText);
        console.log('event is a success');
      });
     }
  }
}
     
</script>
```

Comment: hi. are you want to pass data from child to parent. am I right?

Comment: @ElsaKarami yes.

Answer (score 0):

there are several ways to communicate between parent and child.
if you want to pass data from child to parent, you need to use $emit like the below code

child:

```
    <template>
      <b-button type="is-primary" @click="loadTranslations()">Übersetzen</b-button>
    </template>
    
<script>
export default {
  name: "TranslationButton",

  props: {
    TranslatedText: ''
  },

  methods: {
     loadTranslations() { 
      fetch('http://localhost:3000/ccenter/cc_apis')
        .then(function(response) {
          return response.text();
        })
        .then(function(data) {
          console.log(data);
      })
      .finally((payload) => { // change added
        this.$emit('changeTitle','payload ') // change added
        console.log('event is a success');
      });
     }
  }
}
     
</script>
```

parent:

```
<template>
 <translation-button @changeTitle="ChangeT" />
</template>
methods:{
 ChangeT(title)
  {
   console.log(title)
  },
}
```

this [page](http://this%20(page)%5Bhttps://dev.to/freakflames29/how-to-pass-data-from-child-to-parent-in-vue-js-2d9m%5D%20is%20a%20simple%20example%20related%20to%20your%20problem) is a simple example related to your problem

Comment: thank you for your answer, it makes a lot more sense now. However,  the 'console.log(result)' returns undefined.

Comment: i updated my answer. maybe you don't have any data  in this variable `this.TranslatedText`

Comment: Removed the $event from `changT`, check edited answer

Comment: I also modified the `finally` block

Comment: @ElsaKarami Yes VueTools is showing that 'this.TranslatedText' is undefined, but should this $emit event not pass in the value? aka 'data' should be the value of TranslatedText, and then this should be passed into the parent prop also

Comment: no, when you wanna pass data from parent into the child, you need to use props.

Comment: i have a question. when you fill `this.TranslatedText`?